# Zip a folder in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with things like:

```
%userprofile%/Desktop/FileFolder1
%userprofile%/Desktop/FileFolder2
%userprofile%/Desktop/FileFolder3
```

ect.
and i want it to take each of those folders and zip them. then i need it to move the zip to a specific directory (E:/) and I want it to put the version number (1.0, 1.1, 1.2 ect) and if the disc doesn't have enough space then return an error such as:

```
echo.Error: Not enough space on disc.
```

and when it works:

```
echo.Success.
pause
exit
```

so if i run it twice the disc should have:

```
E:/FileFolder1 1.0.zip
E:/FileFolder2 1.0.zip
E:/FileFolder3 1.0.zip
E:/FileFolder1 1.1.zip
E:/FileFolder2 1.1.zip
E:/FileFolder3 1.1.zip
```

as long as it's not too large. So that's about all I want it to do.
Note: I'll manually add folders to the text file.

FYI I did try to research and everything was either insanly long or i have to download some extension pack or whatever.

EDIT: also I want:

```
echo.Error: No disc inserted.
```

if there is no disc inserted.

Answer (score 0):

1. To iterate over the contents of a text file, read `HELP FOR` and experiment in a command line with...

   ```
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %a IN (file.txt) DO @ECHO %a
   ```
2. For setting an incremental filename, try a counter in a loop. Read `HELP SET` and experiment with

   ```
   set cnt=0
   :again
   set /a cnt+=1
   if exist %dest%\%name%.%cnt%%ext% goto :again
   echo copy %src% %dest%\%name%.%cnt%%ext%
   ```
3. for checking if the disk is inserted you might want to try

   ```
   IF EXIST E:\NUL ECHO E:\ exists!
   ```
4. to check if there is enough free space in the disk, you may use `wmic`. Filter the output with `findstr`, and "pipe" the result to a variable with a `FOR`. Experiment with..

   ```
   FOR /F "tokens=1" %i IN ('wmic logicaldisk get name^,freespace^|findstr /I "E:"') Do @echo free = %i
   ```

   and then to check if a file fits, compare the result of the previous command with the file's size, see `HELP CALL` (where the ~z modifier is explained), and try

   ```
    IF %free% GEQ %~z1 ECHO %1 fits in E: [%free%^>%~z1]
   ```

I leave as an exercise to you the way to put all this pieces together.

Comment: you need to use an especialized tool. There are many file compression utilities available. Most have a command line interface. **7-zip** http://www.7-zip.org is the one I use and probably one of the most populars.